# Surf a site from different country IP

Tags: php, proxy, ip

I want to surf a website using proxy ip of UK.

Does this can be possible in php?
If yes , please let me know

Comment: You should include in post what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 2):

Proxy can be followed. Better way is to use VPN.

But if you want proxy there are some sites for example http://www.hidemyass.com

You can always download a website from php server which is in UK and save or show it. I found also on this site the example with proxy http://www.fromzerotoseo.com/scraping-websites-php-curl-proxy/

```
<?php
function getPage($proxy, $url, $referer, $agent, $header, $timeout) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);

$result['EXE'] = curl_exec($ch);
$result['INF'] = curl_getinfo($ch);
$result['ERR'] = curl_error($ch);

curl_close($ch);

return $result;
}
?>
```

usage:

```
 $result = getPage(
'[proxy IP]:[port]', // use valid proxy
'http://www.google.com/search?q=twitter',
'http://www.google.com/',
'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.8) Gecko/2009032609 Firefox/3.0.8',
1,
5);
```